# Concatenate multiple videos with a black screen loop into one video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing

I am using ffmpeg to join a bunch of videos together.
 
I am using the classic join ffmpeg code:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i joinlist.txt -c copy joinedfile.mp4
```

but the problem is that the videos are of different formats, encodings, but the same size: all 640x480. I want to join them all and put a black screen video with no sound every other video:

```
video1 + black_screen_video + video2 + black_screen_video + video3 ...
```

I generated a black screen video of 2 seconds duration using:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=640x480:d=2 black_screen_video.mp4
```

so all of the videos are of the same size: 640x480, and 25 fps but different codecs. The videos have sound, except for the black screen video.
I can't do anything manual, because the number of videos are around several hundred. So it has got to be an automatic way to do all this.

When I joined them together using the above code, the resulting video does not play correctly at all.

I know that I have to re-encode them, but how to do this to all these videos at once, with one line of code?

Update:
I am already using with success this code to join them together, but only three, if I have more than one hundred, it is time consuming to write down one by one:

```
ffmpeg -i vid1.avi -i vid2.avi -i vid3.avi -filter_complex "[0:v:0] [0:a:0] [1:v:0] [1:a:0] [2:v:0] [2:a:0] concat=n=3:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4
```

but this is joining only the videos, not looping the black screen video. When I do with black screen, ffmpeg gives me stream matching errors.

### **update:**

here is the console image:
[image]

### 2nd update:

a very long list of errors in red, of which a screenshot here:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the concat demuxer, as before.

Your text file will be:

```
file 'vid1.avi'
file 'black_screen_video.mp4'
file 'vid2.avi'
file 'black_screen_video.mp4'
file 'vid3.avi'
file 'black_screen_video.mp4'
...
```

And your command:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i joinlist.txt joinedfile.mp4
```

You also need to include a dummy audio in the black screen video.

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=640x480:d=2 -f lavfi -i aevalsrc=0:c=2:d=2 black_screen_video.mp4
```

Comment: yes, adding an audio stream to the black screen video helped to bypass this problem. But, the videos are not showng, i hear the sound of the videos but not the images! why is that?

Comment: Show the full console output of the command you ran. And which player did you test in?

Comment: i updated by adding the image, and I used vlc and also media player classic klite codec. it still is the same, complete black screen with sound only.

Comment: by the way, i generated .avi black screen video and my output is .avi also.

Comment: Try this command, and see if the command runs without errors : `ffmpeg -i vid1.avi vid1new.avi`. If no errors, and the resulting video plays ok, then substitute it in the concat list and try.

Comment: the result is ok, what do you mean by substitute? what with what?

Comment: In the concat list, replace vid1.avi with vid1new.avi and rerun concat. You may have to do this for all files which have damaged headers.

Comment: yes! it worked! but there is a problem, i lost a bit in the quality of the videos when I run the command for each of the videos, separately. I mean, the quality dropped significantly, how can I repair the files and keep the quality. but the rest works, i mean concat command works with these new files!

Comment: Use a high bitrate, when generating the new files `-b:v 1500k`

Answer (score 1):

Hope it helps also had the same issue and fixed it by changing all the videos to the same frame rate and also audio to the same frequency with this command
`ffmpeg -y -i in.mp4 -vf fps=60 -ar 48000 out.mp4`

convert and the concat again

Please vote if helped (:

Comment: Since you're using filters anyway you can do it all in one command using the concat filter instead of the concat demuxer.